# React Native Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzhw

Tags: android, react-native

I just did few changes in JS side of my project without updating any packages or something but now I get these errors..

> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzbw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.1)

..... continues
```

So probably some packages are making this conflict which use google play services, so here is my package.json.

```
{
  "name": "xx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^0.2.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^0.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.4",
    "react-native-admob": "^2.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-iap": "^3.3.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^3.6.0",
    "react-native-sound": "^0.11.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!react-native|react-navigation)/"
    ],
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

    project.ext.react = [
        entryFile: "index.js",
        enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    ]

    apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

    /**
     * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
     *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
     *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
     * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
     * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
     * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
     */
    def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

    /**
     * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
     */
    def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

    /**
     * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
     *
     * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
     * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
     *
     * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
     * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
     * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
     * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
     */
    def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

    /**
     * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
     *
     * This should be set on project.ext.react and mirrored here.  If it is not set
     * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
     * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
     */
    def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xx"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
            versionCode 50
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        splits {
            abi {
                reset()
                enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
                universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
                include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
            }
        }
        signingConfigs {
            debug {
                storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                storePassword 'android'
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
            }
            release {
                 if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                     storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                     storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                     keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                     keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
                 }
             }
        }
        buildTypes {
            debug {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
                // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
                // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
                minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }

            }
        }

        packagingOptions {
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
            pickFirst '**/x86/libjsc.so'
            pickFirst '**/armeabi-v7a/libjsc.so'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

        if (enableHermes) {
          def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermesvm/android/";
          debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
          releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
        } else {
          implementation jscFlavor
        }
    }

    // Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
    // puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
    task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
        from configurations.compile
        into 'libs'
    }

    apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true
```

Comment: have you tried `./gradlew clean` and rebuild your project after making the changes?

Comment: yeah I did try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have tried many combinations by deleting packages may have connection to google services.

I have found the solution by trying, this bug was caused by react-native-admob.

In the end of file in dependencies in

> node_modules/react-native-admob/android/build.gradle

There was

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'

I changed it to

> implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'

Hope it may be helpful.